# Function from a referenced library which has function pointers as parameters

Tags: vb.net, delegates, visual-studio-2013, function-pointers

UPDATE: Changed question to match updated code and be more specific to my problem.

I have no experience working with `VB.Net` or `Visual Studio`, and limited experience with `C`. I have been trying to learn about `Function Pointers` and `Delegates` but still don't fully understand them.

I am writing a project in VB.Net that makes calls to methods from a dll file.

C code from the dll file:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;

typedef void (__stdcall *fp_setbaud)(WORD);
typedef short (__stdcall *fp_get)(WORD);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_put)(BYTE);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_flush)(void);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_delay)(WORD);


BYTE __stdcall InitRelay(fp_setbaud _setbaud, fp_get _get, fp_put _put,
            fp_flush _flush, fp_delay _delay) { ... }

BYTE __stdcall ReadRelay(void){ ... }
```

VB.net Module code:

```
Declare Function InitRelay Lib "Z:\Devel\RelayAPI\Debug\RelayAPI.dll" (ByVal setbaud As Action(Of Short), ByVal getit As Func(Of Short, Short), ByVal putit As Action(Of Short), ByVal flushit As Action, ByVal delay As Action(Of Short)) As Byte

Declare Function ReadRelay Lib "Z:\Devel\RelayAPI\Debug\RelayAPI.dll" () As Byte

Public Sub setbaud(ByVal baud As Short)
    ...
End Sub

Public Function getit(ByVal timeout As Short) As Short
    ...
End Function

Public Sub putit(ByVal dat As Short)
    ...
End Sub

Public Sub flushit()
    ...
End Sub

Public Function delaymS(ByVal mS As Short) As Short
    ...
End Function
```

VB.Net Form Code:

```
    Dim a As Byte

    Call InitRelay(AddressOf moduleCode.setbaud, AddressOf moduleCode.getit,      
                   AddressOf moduleCode.putit, AddressOf moduleCode.flushit, 
                   AddressOf moduleCode.delaymS)

    a = ReadRelay()
```

The error I am getting is when I call `a = ReadRelay()`  from within my VB.Net code. The error appears on each one of the parameters and says the following:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred
```

The `ReadRelay` function uses all of the functions passed to the `InitRelay` function. `InitRelay` is called prior to the `ReadRelay` and gives me no errors. I am assuming the error still has to do with how I am passing the function pointers to the `InitRelay` function.

I have been using [this website](http://www.marvintest.com/KnowledgeBase/KBArticle.aspx?ID=210) to try to figure out the type conversions but I still don't know what to do.

Does anyone have any information on what I should be doing to properly call these functions?

**EDIT**

New Delegate declarations as suggested below:

```
Private setBaudDelegate As New Action(Of Short)(AddressOf modCommStuff.setbaud)
Private getItDelegate As New Func(Of Short, Short)(AddressOf modCommStuff.getit)
Private putItDelegate As New Action(Of Short)(AddressOf modCommStuff.putit)
Private flushItDelegate As New Action(AddressOf modCommStuff.flushit)
Private delayItDelegate As New Action(Of Short)(AddressOf modCommStuff.delaymS)

....

 Call InitRelay(setBaudDelegate, getItDelegate, putItDelegate, flushItDelegate, delayItDelegate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pin the delegates so that they are not garbage collected.

```
dim handle as GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ObjectToPin, GCHandleType.Pinned)
```

Don't forget to free the object after you are done with it using `.Free`

```
handle.Free()
```

More information is available at this website.
http://manski.net/2012/06/pinvoke-tutorial-pinning-part-4/

**UPDATE 1**

After reading more it looks like pinning delegates is not specifically allowed, but you still have to keep the delegate in memory.  I would try creating instance variables for your delegates and keeping them in fields defined in your form's code.  This should be enough to keep the delegates from getting garbage collected and keep the unmanaged "stubs" from getting cleaned up.

> Along the same lines, managed Delegates can be marshaled to unmanaged
>   code, where they are exposed as unmanaged function pointers. Calls on
>   those pointers will perform an unmanaged to managed transition; a
>   change in calling convention; entry into the correct AppDomain; and
>   any necessary argument marshaling. Clearly the unmanaged function
>   pointer must refer to a fixed address. It would be a disaster if the
>   GC were relocating that! This leads many applications to create a
>   pinning handle for the delegate. This is completely unnecessary. The
>   unmanaged function pointer actually refers to a native code stub that
>   we dynamically generate to perform the transition & marshaling. This
>   stub exists in fixed memory outside of the GC heap.
>
> However, the application is responsible for somehow extending the
>   lifetime of the delegate until no more calls will occur from unmanaged
>   code. The lifetime of the native code stub is directly related to the
>   lifetime of the delegate. Once the delegate is collected, subsequent
>   calls via the unmanaged function pointer will crash or otherwise
>   corrupt the process.

**Update 2**
Here is an example with actual code. I only did it for something that takes a single argument, if you need it adjusted for the additional arguments let me know.

```
Private Sub InitRelay(d1 As Action(Of Short))
    'This sub represents the InitRelay function exported by your library.  You wouldn't      actually have this directly in your code.
End Sub


Private Sub setBaud(baud As Short)
    'This is the SetBaud sub in your module
End Sub

'This would be in your form code, at the class level (outside all subs)
Private setBaudDelegate As New Action(Of Short)(AddressOf setBaud)

'This sub is whatever sub in your code calls InitRelay
Private Sub Test()
    InitRelay(setBaudDelegate)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mean writing something along the lines of `dim handle as GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc( AddressOf.setbaud, GCHandle.pinned)`

edit: I know very little about VB.net so I'm just making sure I understand which variables you are saying to create instances of.

Comment: That was my initial idea before the update I posted.  It turns out that Alloc doesn't work for delegates.  My update suggests creating local fields on the form to store the delegates and keep them in scope.  Something like `Private setBaudDelegate as new Action(of Short)(AddressOf moduleCode.setbaud`).  Then passing in `setBaudDelegate` to InitRelay instead of the `AddressOf moduleCode.setbaud` directly.  You would need to do this for each of your delegate arguments.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I updated my question with the new code I put in, but I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark (I'm running out of ideas).  The calling convention that the library is using my be different than the one .net assumes by default.  Try applying the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute to your delegates and switching them to `CDECL`.  `<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Private setBaudDelegate As New Action(Of Short)(AddressOf setBaud)`

Comment: Adding that to my code, it requires me to use `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`, and then gives me an error on the attribute saying `Attribute 'UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute' cannot be applied to 'setBaudDelegate' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.`